# Limit of trigonometric function (cotangent)

Tags: analysis

I need to solve the following problem:
$\lim_{x\to 3}(x-3) \cot{\pi x}$.
Can anyone give me a hint? I have no idea.

Comment: You can transform to a limit to $0$ and express the cotangent as the well-known ratio.

Comment: Well the ratio is $\frac{cos{\pi x}}{sin{\pi x}}$. But how do I transform the limit?

Comment: Shift the variable.

Comment: Can you show me how it is done, please?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 3}(x-3) \cot{\pi x}=\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{(x-3)\cos{\pi x}}{\sin{\pi x}}=\frac{0}{0}.$$.

Now, you can use  L'Hopital rule, just one and then you will get your answer.
I hope that helps

Comment: We are not allowed to use L‘Hospital (yet) :(

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 3}(x-3) \cot{\pi x}=-\lim_{x\to 0}x \cot{\pi x}=-\frac1\pi\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\pi x}{\sin \pi x} \cos{\pi x}.$$

Comment: Are you sure, that this is right because wolfram alpha says that it us now a different answer.

Comment: @Ilja: care to tell it ?

Comment: The answer is supposed to be $\frac{1}{\pi}$